# App crash on last item deleted in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView and populating data from the database and storing it into arrayLists. i've also added an onLongClickListener() to the recycler view which removes the long clicked row. Everything works fine but when I delete the last the app crashes and i get Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException index:0 size:0.

here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AlarmRecyclerViewInterface {

    FloatingActionButton mAlarmAddButton;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    AlarmsDBhelperClass mAlarmsDBhelperClass;
    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <String> modeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> minArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Switch mSwitch;
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);
    ImageView emptyImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Initializing RecyclerView, DatabaseHelperClass, FAB button, The ON OFF switch & the empty ImageView
        mAlarmsDBhelperClass = new AlarmsDBhelperClass(getApplicationContext());
        mAlarmAddButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarmADD);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.alarmList);
        mSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switchONOFF);
        emptyImageView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

        //DividerItemDecoration class is used for getting a vertical line between rows of RecyclerView
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        //Getting a writable reference of the Database.
        db = mAlarmsDBhelperClass.getWritableDatabase();

        //Retrieving values from the database and storing them in custom ArrayLists
        boolean isDataEmpty = getAlarm(db);

        //Checking if our arrayList is empty? if yes then display some empty list text or an image
        if (!isDataEmpty){
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_alarm_black_white);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //FAB Event handling
        mAlarmAddButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.addalarm);
        mAlarmAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAlarm.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

       //Warping up with the recyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    public boolean getAlarm(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM alarms", new String[]{});
        boolean rowExists;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                nameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                modeArrayList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                repeatArrayList.add(cursor.getString(4));
                hoursArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(5)));
                minArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(6)));
                rowExists = true;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else {
            rowExists = false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return rowExists;
    }

    //RecyclerView's onClick()
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //RecyclerView's onLongClick()
    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {
        hoursArrayList.remove(position);
        //Updating the recyclerView
        alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //Deleting the row from the database
        db.delete("alarms","hours=?",new String[]{hoursArrayList.get(position)});
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

here's my RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.AlarmView> {
    //Variables for the main recycler view
    private ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> minArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> modeArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> nameArrayList;
    private AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface;

    public AlarmAdapter(ArrayList<String> hours,ArrayList<String> mins,ArrayList<String> mode,ArrayList<String> repeat,ArrayList<String> name,AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface){
        this.hoursArrayList = hours;
        this.minArrayList = mins;
        this.modeArrayList = mode;
        this.nameArrayList = name;
        this.repeatArrayList = repeat;
        this.mInterface = mInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_profile,parent,false);
        return new AlarmView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmView holder, int position) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)) < 10 ){
            holder.hours.setText("0"+hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.hours.setText(hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)) < 10){
            holder.mins.setText("0"+minArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.mins.setText(minArrayList.get(position));
        }
        holder.repeat.setText(repeatArrayList.get(position));
        holder.mode.setText(modeArrayList.get(position));
        holder.name.setText(nameArrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hoursArrayList.size();
    }

    /*ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            nameArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            modeArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            repeatArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            hoursArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            minArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };*/

    public class AlarmView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView hours,mins,repeat,name,mode;
        public AlarmView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hours = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHOUR);
            mins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMins);
            repeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatDays);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            mode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMode);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can I ask, why are the class member variables in MainActivity all set without access-modifiers? i.e. private, public, protected? also why did you instantiate like that not inside the onCreate method?

Comment: @EvOladLuPiZ to access them outside the onCreate() i.e., in the onLongClick() listener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ### Crash :- IndexOutOfBoundsException

  - #### Reason :- You removed data from the list and after that, you again fetching this value from the list to remove data from the database at that time it will crash because it has no value as you deleted data.
  - #### Solution :- You can delete first from the database and after that remove from your list.

> - ### Example :-
>
>   Replace below onLongClick() Override method in your class.

```
//RecyclerView's onLongClick()
@Override
public void onLongItemClick(int position) {

    // Best way to remove data from list
    if(hoursArrayList != null && hoursArrayList.size() > 0){

        //Deleting the row from the database
        db.delete("alarms","hours=?",new String[]{hoursArrayList.get(position)});

        //Delete from your list if you successfully removed data from your database.
        hoursArrayList.remove(position);

        //Updating the recyclerView
        if(alarmAdapter){
            alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

        //Message to show User.
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```